# Using AngularJs - Angular Material or Jquery to display a window template

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-material

How to create a button (similar to FAB speed dial from angular material) or something similar to display a small window next to the button clicked, the small window only has a text area and a button inside, I would like to use Angular Material preferably or AngularJs routing or Jquery.

I have been trying using bottomsheets and FAB speed dial from angular material but without success.

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If angular material doesn't have the functionality you are looking for built in (which I don't believe it does), you should just write a directive for it yourself. I would 'probably' write a directive that, when clicked, reveals a sibling or child element.

You could use a directive with a non-isolated scope to pass the data from the box you are creating to the rest of your application.

The code would probably look *roughly* something like this:

```
angular.directive('smallInputModalButton', function() {
    scope: {}, // or false, up to you
    controller: function () { $scope.isShown = false; },
    template: '<div ng-hide="isShown"><input></input><button></button></div>',
    link: function( scope, elem, attrs, controller ) {

        elem.on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            scope.isShown = !scope.isShown;
        });
     }
}
```

Make sure you position the element that has the `smallInputModal` attribute on it relatively, with the `#isShown` div positioned relatively so that you can easily nest them next to each other.

If you want to be really thorough, you could create a directive that acts as a button, which communicates with another directive which has logic for showing/hiding the modal.

If you look in popular libraries, including ngMaterial, they do something of that sort.

For simple use cases, the answer above will work fine.

Comment: Thanks nikk, directive was good idea, and it is working, i just have got a little issue, a click at any button in the window open the template. do u know how i can attach the trigger event in the "link:" just to the button required?

Comment: Not sure right off the top of my head—but what I would do is throw a ```debugger``` statement into the linking function i.e. ```link function(scope,elem,attrs,controller) { debugger } ) and once you're there inspect the ```elem``` element. You'll only wan the click to bind to the button, so maybe the code will be something like ```elem.firstChild.on('click'...``` or something similar to that. Let me know how that goes.

Comment: Well, it was easy as expected. i just wrapped the template into a container with a ng-hide directive and the button required change the value to true or false when clicked. so far, all working ok. Thanks for your help.